# Description logics with decision problems within NP

Tags: time-complexity

Is there any description logic where important decision problems (e.g. abox consistency or concept satisfiability) lie within NP with respect to their time complexity?

The well-researched family of $\mathcal{ALC}$-based logics might not work since even for $\mathcal{ALC}$, problems are PSpace-complete. Neither would the $\mathcal{EL}$ family since the problems are at least CoNP.

Some restriction thereof might work, though, although I couldn't find any so far.

Answer (score 1):

Can see here https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#Computational_Properties  for OWL-EL, OWL-QL and OWL-RL

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the only example I know is subsumption in FL$^-$, which actually is in P. On the other hand, subsumption in full FL is co-NP hard.
A standard reference is Levesque and Brachman, [*Expressiveness and tractability in knowledge representation and reasoning*](http://www.inf.unibz.it/%7Efranconi/dl/course/2006/articles/BrachLev.pdf).
[Here](https://www.inf.unibz.it/%7Efranconi/dl/course/slides/struct-DL/flminus.pdf) you can find more about FL$^-$, while [these note](https://www.inf.unibz.it/%7Efranconi/dl/course/dlhb/dlhb-03.pdf) are devoted to  the computational complexity of satisfiability and subsumption in several description logics.